# Lightbox is overwriting som CSS classes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on this [lightbox code - on codepen](https://codepen.io/svelts/pen/VYxPWW/). So everythink is working on the pen.

Now I am trying to use it on [this page][2] where I have to use the gallery live.

The problem is now that the lightbox is flying way over the menu when you click on an image. So there must be some classes there is conflicting? I made some prefix on quite a lot of the classes, to avoid this problem. When I look in the inspect window I cannot figure out which classes there is conflicting.

Can anybody help me out here?

**NB:** I do not have access to other CSS/JS than you see on the below code:

```js
$(window).load(function() {

  $("section img").click(function() {
    $(".lightbox").fadeIn(300);
    $(".lightbox").append("<img src='" + $(this).attr("src") + "' alt='" + $(this).attr("alt") + "' />");
    $(".filter").css("background-image", "url(" + $(this).attr("src") + ")");
    /*$(".title").append("<h1>" + $(this).attr("alt") + "</h1>");*/
    $("html").css("overflow", "hidden");
    if ($(this).is(":last-child")) {
      $(".arrowr").css("display", "none");
      $(".arrowl").css("display", "block");
    } else if ($(this).is(":first-child")) {
      $(".arrowr").css("display", "block");
      $(".arrowl").css("display", "none");
    } else {
      $(".arrowr").css("display", "block");
      $(".arrowl").css("display", "block");
    }
  });

  $(".close").click(function() {
    $(".lightbox").fadeOut(300);
    $("h1").remove();
    $(".lightbox img").remove();
    $("html").css("overflow", "auto");
  });

  $(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
      $(".lightbox").fadeOut(300);
      $(".lightbox img").remove();
      $("html").css("overflow", "auto");
    }
  });

  $(".arrowr").click(function() {
    var imgSrc = $(".lightbox img").attr("src");
    var search = $("section").find("img[src$='" + imgSrc + "']");
    var newImage = search.next().attr("src");
    /*$(".lightbox img").attr("src", search.next());*/
    $(".lightbox img").attr("src", newImage);
    $(".filter").css("background-image", "url(" + newImage + ")");

    if (!search.next().is(":last-child")) {
      $(".arrowl").css("display", "block");
    } else {
      $(".arrowr").css("display", "none");
    }
  });

  $(".arrowl").click(function() {
    var imgSrc = $(".lightbox img").attr("src");
    var search = $("section").find("img[src$='" + imgSrc + "']");
    var newImage = search.prev().attr("src");
    /*$(".lightbox img").attr("src", search.next());*/
    $(".lightbox img").attr("src", newImage);
    $(".filter").css("background-image", "url(" + newImage + ")");

    if (!search.prev().is(":first-child")) {
      $(".arrowr").css("display", "block");
    } else {
      $(".arrowl").css("display", "none");
    }
  });

});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300);
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
section {
  column-width: 300px;
  column-gap: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

section img {
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.lightbox {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
  background: #7f8c8d;
  perspective: 1000;
}

.filter {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  filter: blur(20px);
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.lightbox img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateY(0deg);
  max-height: 95vh;
  max-width: calc(95vw - 100px);
  transition: 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.4, 1);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}


/*.lightbox:hover img{
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateY(180deg);
}*/

[class^="arrow"] {
  height: 200px;
  width: 50px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
}

[class^="arrow"]:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}

.arrowr {
  right: 0;
}

.arrowr:after {
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.arrowl {
  left: 0;
}

.arrowl:after {
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  margin: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.close:after,
.close:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #e74c3c;
}

.close:after {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
}

.close:before {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg);
}

.title {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #000;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/700/600?image=634" />
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/700/300?image=455" />
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/1500/700?image=629" />
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/700?image=594" />
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/700/450?image=417" />
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/700/400?image=410" />
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/700/550?image=628" />
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/700/450?image=421" />
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/700/567?image=572" />
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/700/978?image=623" />
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/700/654?image=621" />
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/700/500?image=423" />
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/1000/654?image=930" />
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/700/950?image=1045" />
</section>
<div class="lightbox">
  <div class="title"></div>
  <div class="filter"></div>
  <div class="arrowr"></div>
  <div class="arrowl"></div>
  <div class="close"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: either in the JS or CSS that you have --  Set the `z-index` for `.sbp-lightbox` to something greater than 4 (The `z-index` of the menu)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think it is more a question of getting the lightbox to stay in the content area.

Comment: Well technically it *is* in the content area ..  But not the way you -think ..   Use your console ..  It's inside of `wrapper` div ..  And it's properties are correct ..  it's just `top:0; left:0` as a `child` of `wrapper`

Comment: Strike that --   add `left:0` to `.sbp-lightbox` --  I failed to see the `position` was `fixed`

Comment: Ok thanks a lot Zak

Comment: Did that fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Being the `.sbp-lightbox` element is `fixed` and has no `left` defined, it's receiving it's X coordinate from it's parent.

Add `left:0` to `.sbp-lightbox`

Also give it a `z-index` of `9`.  That should fix your issue with the menu over the box.